# Reference to NEC spec on dryer breakers

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, dryer, nec

I just moved into a newly constructed house and have found several 240 breakers to be of the incorrect amperage.

The breaker for the dryer is 25 Amps but everything I've read says that the NEC requires a 30A breaker (I don't have a dryer yet so no idea what it will want, but again I keep reading 30A is common).

Is there a definitive reference on this - a link to the NEC, or even a photocopy of the spec? The company that did the electrical work is pushing back and so I'm going through the builder.

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: Picture of the outlet? The NEC only tells you *how* to wire an outlet. The manufacturer of the device will tell you *what* outlet it needs.

Answer (score 3):

30 amps is common for most dryers but not all.  Most household dryers do use 30 amp circuits, but there are also small apartment dryers that can be used on regular household 15/20 amp circuits, and imagine big commercial ones that take much larger size.  So one size does not make sense.

I'm not sure which section it would be in, but I believe NEC would say that the device/appliance will state what size/amount of amps it requires on the circuit and NEC says the breaker size and wire gauge that will work/needed to power the device/appliance.

It seems odd the builder would put in a 25 amp dryer circuit, but it has been a long time since I checked. There might be dryers working on 25 amps now.

25 amps would need the same 10 gauge wire as a 30 amp circuit, so possible only a breaker change will be needed.  I would check the wire/cable gauge to be sure.

Comment: 3 bedroom house. They put in 40 amp breakers on a 50 amp EV charger circuit that drove me to look at everything.

Answer (score 2):

NEC 240.4(D) requires 10 AWG copper or 8 AWG aluminum wire for a 25A circuit.  That size also works for 30A.

NEC 210.21 requires a 30A receptacle be fed by a 30A breaker.

Are you sure you aren't looking at your **water heater** breaker? Most tanked resistance water heaters are 4500 VA continuous, and that only requires a 25A circuit. And they are hardwired so the socket is not a factor.  Many people use 30A breakers for water heaters, but 25A will suffice.

Perhaps they mixed up the two breakers.

Comment: On demand water heater so no.